# Configuring identical home screens on multiple devices

Tags: home-screen, customization, multiple-devices

I need to modify the home screen icons' disposition and add new shortcuts, but I need to do it programmatically from a flashable ZIP through recovery.

I need this because I will have to do it on hundreds of devices (tablets).

Can anyone point me in the right direction where to look at? (which apk or xml file?)

Comment: Since you're looking to write a program to do what you want, this is very close to being off-topic here; Android programming questions should be asked on [so]. (Please read the [FAQ].) However, being able to deploy multiple devices with the same homescreen layout is certainly of interest to other Enterprise users. So I think this question is okay here. I am concerned, though, that you've already pre-selected your solution.

Comment: Is using a 3rd-party home screen replacement/launcher app an acceptable solution?

Comment: Thanks Al, that sounded to me the quickest option, since i've already found how to modify the wallpaper through framework-res.apk...but i'm open to different ways to achieve this!

Comment: Chahk, if with trebuchet what i want to do is not possible, then yes, it might be a solution.

Comment: It must be possible, as most ROMs I see start out with a few icons on the home screen. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: That's exactly what i thought SaintWacko, hope someone with more knowledge will show up

Answer (score 1):

I think i found a way to do that:
decompressing Launcher2.apk (trebuchet Launcher app) i found an interesting file named
default_workspace.xml under /res/xml folder of the app.

```
<appwidget launcher:className="com.estrongs.android.taskmanager.widget.TmWidgetProvider" launcher:packageName="com.estrongs.android.taskmanager" launcher:screen="2" launcher:x="5" launcher:y="0" launcher:spanX="1" launcher:spanY="1" />
<favorite launcher:className="com.android.music.activitymanagement.TopLevelActivity" launcher:packageName="com.google.android.music" launcher:screen="2" launcher:x="5" launcher:y="2" />
```

with all the necessary to place widgets and icons on different workspaces and XY position.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you get Nova Launcher (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en) you can backup and restore from the settings menu.  Use this with Dropbox and you've got an easy end to end solution